# how to specials add new string before 4 characters of all keyword in old string

Tags: php, string, addition

**Example:**

```
$oldstring = "How to Formatqw101-put returns between paragraphsre51-for linebreak add 2 spaces at endfd54-italic_ or **bold**se65-indent code by 4 spaces";
$newstring = "<br/>";
```

I want to add $newstring in every before 4 character of "-"  so when success look like this

```
How to Format<br/>qw101-put returns between paragraphs<br/>re51-for linebreak add 2 spaces at end<br/>fd54-italic_ or **bold**<br/>se65-indent code by 4 spaces
```

Comment: Check out the explode() function.

Comment: qw101 is 5 characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$oldstring = "How to Formatqw101-put returns between paragraphsre51-for linebreak add 2 spaces at endfd54-italic_ or **bold**se65-indent code by 4 spaces";
$arr = explode(' ', $oldstring);
$res = array();
foreach($arr as $item) {
    if(strpos($item, '-') !== false) {
        $pos = strpos($item, '-');
        $item = substr_replace($item, '<br/>', $pos-4, 0);
    }
    $res[] = $item.' ';
}
echo implode('', $res);
```